# ¿Se pueden crear condiciones de filtrado complejas en google apps scrips para spreadsheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Hola tengo una relacion de valores como aparece en la imágen.
Quiero construir condiciones de filtrado de tipo [ (A2=true && B2=true) || C2=true ], es decir filtrar por una convianacion de condiciones de varias columnas.
Por ejemplo (A2=true ||B1=true||B2=true||C1=true||C2=true)

Solo he encontrado condiciones que se aplican acumulativamente a cada columna,
si en la primera pongo A2=true y en la segunda B1=true la condición que construye es (A2=true && B1=true).

[image: Columnas con diferentes valores]

Answer (score 0):

Parece que he encontrado una solución, en mi opinión, algo chapucera pero que para mi caso concreto funciona.

como lo que quiero es que me devuelva la fila si cualquier dato de la fila es true, pues le he contruido la formula  `.whenFormulaSatisfied('=countif(F11:J11;true)>0')` que me cuenta los trues de una linea y si es mayor que 0 me la devuelve.

```
function filtre2() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('F10:J57').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('F10:J57').createFilter();
  spreadsheet.getRange('F10').activate();
  var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
  .whenFormulaSatisfied('=countif(F11:J11;true)>0')
  .build();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(10, criteria);
};
```

Gracias por vuestro tiempo.

Comment: Puedes usar TextFinder. Revisa [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67796905/5587982) y los enlaces en ella.